# NPM 'crypto' returning different hash values than online generators (node)

Tags: node.js, hash, sha

I am probably not using the `crypto` module correctly, maybe someone can help me out.

The goal is to find the sha-256 hash of a file dropped in a `dropzone`. The problem is that the hash being returned is different from online hash checkers (which are returning the seemingly correct values). Here is my code:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");

handleOnDrop = file => {
    hash.update(file);
    const hashOutput = hash.digest("hex");
    console.log(hashOutput);
  };
```

Crypto docs - https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_node_js_crypto_constants

I am fairly sure the hash values I am getting from this code is not just the file name, I checked a few permutations with the online checkers.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is `file`?

Comment: And what is `hash`? How do you create it?

Comment: File is input as a blob by the client (through react-dropzone). Hash is from the `crypto` docs, I edited the original post to include that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropzone events return a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) class object, this object is based on the [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) class and doesn't provide direct access to the data of the file.  In order to use the data in the file, you must use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) class as outlined in the [Mozilla examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images)

Crypto is expecting a buffer when you call `hash.update`, but `file` isn't a Buffer like it would be in these [examples](https://www.hacksparrow.com/how-to-generate-md5-sha1-sha512-sha256-checksum-hashes-in-node-js.html). Dropping a Blob into `hash.update` probably doesn't have the behavior you are expecting.

So, assuming you're using WebPack to provide access to the Node standard libraries, your code should need to do something like this:

```
  handleOnDrop = ((file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = ((event) => {
      hash.update(Buffer.from(event.target.result));
      const hashOutput = hash.digest("hex");
      console.log(hashOutput);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Code is not working as is, getting an error `Error: cannot read as File: [{}]`  Your response is very helpful though..I think I'm on the right path, thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. The only modification is that I place `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)` on top of `reader.onload`

My other issue was solved by creating a new `create-react-app`. Not sure why that helped.